A news release has been published showing some advancement in the use or performance of generative AI systems. Should the ban be reconsidered?
I've read an article saying that:

a generative AI system has outperformed many/most humans on some benchmark or competition
a company/survey indicates increasing usage/desire to use generative AI for coding
a new generative AI system has improved capability to reason in some manner

When the Stack Overflow ban on generative AI systems was enacted some years ago, generative AI was worse, and did not have this newly announced capability.  Should the ban be reconsidered?

I'd like this better if it were hammered into more of a [meta-tag:faq-proposed] shape, like "why aren't such news releases taken as a reason to reconsider the ban?". (Also, I fundamentally disagree that anything an LLM can do, even in principle, can fairly be called "reasoning".)

@KarlKnechtel I was aiming for that general format, but also writing from the perspective of someone asking the question, who would generally be proposing that the ban should be reconsidered, rather than asking why it isn't already being reconsidered.  That said, I think your framing also works, and if there's a general feeling that that would be an improvement, I'd welcome that edit.  I also didn't tag it with that because I don't know if it's common enough to be an FAQ...but I suppose that's where the "proposed" part comes in.  I'd be amenable to the tag being added as well.

The one benefit of writing it like how Karl suggested is that it picks up less downvotes. Right now it reads like you're for allowing AIGC on the network.

I'm not happy with the certainty expressed in the answer about all possible future developments. I guess it comes from the question not being specific about the exact publications. It is deliberately not clear enough there. Would I have to ask it I would add qualifiers like "unlikely, recent". In truth the ban or any other artificial rule should be reconsidered regularly. However, I can also predict the reception, so I just leave it as is.

No
Improvements in LLM research/technology do not address the fundamental reasons behind the ban, no matter how impressive those improvements are.
Generally, these news releases relate to either specific benchmarks or competitions, typically related to algorithmic problems (a small minority of Stack Overflow content), to solving well-understood existing problems, or to closely supervised use by professional engineers for writing portions of code relating to already-solved problems where they're mostly serving as a time-saver for something the author already knows how to do, or could easily look up (often on an existing Stack Overflow question).
These results in constrained circumstances do not mean that all generative AI usage should be allowed in all circumstances. While such results certainly represent useful capabilities in some contexts, they are very different than the context of Stack Overflow questions.
Stack Overflow questions cover a vast range of topics, including new libraries (or versions) that the public has no current experience with.  Questions that follow the site's content guidelines (and are not duplicates) tend to not have straightforward answers that are already documented. Many require debugging, code inspection of dependencies, and trial and error—none of which are within the capabilities of current-generation generative AI systems.
The main problem with usage of generative AI tools on Stack Overflow is that people are wholesale copying content from them and often not checking its correctness at all (often because they are not familiar with the technology), or at least not checking it thoroughly enough (and do not catch when it introduces errors that a human would not have made).  When asked about topics they do not know the answer to, many generative AI systems often produce answers that are confident, well-written, logically sound, and completely wrong.  Vetting these answers at Stack Overflow's scale is infeasible, due to the asymmetry between the effort required to generate them (often under a minute) and the effort required to verify them (many minutes, sometimes hours).

"many generative AI systems often produce answers that are confident, well-written, logically sound, and completely wrong." And sometimes they have impeccable prose but are logically incoherent or self-contradictory, at least to someone with domain knowledge.

Why bother with AI-assisted-SO when I can use the AI directly? SO's unique selling point is that the answers are from a human expert curated by humans.

@MT1 As a reader, what's wrong with answers that are partly from an AI but curated by humans?

Finding that answer at any point in time between its initial posting and the arrival of a human expert who takes the time to properly vet/curate it. Which, at the scale of SO, is likely to be a significant amount of time. (I occasionally find completely wrong answers from a decade ago, at least in more obscure topics.) This is what the answer's last paragraph attempts to explain.

@FranckDernoncourt - The problem is I have never seen the humans successfully curate the AI content, every single bloody answer I have ever seen generate and subsequently submitted to this platform was full of hallucination nonsensical information

@CodyGray "Finding that answer at any point in time between its initial posting and the arrival of a human expert who takes the time to properly vet/curate it." What if the answer is  curated at the time of posting (which is what I had in mind and seems obvious to me)

@SecurityHound It's pretty easy to curate AI content.

@FranckDernoncourt - It hasn’t been easy. I have flagged dozens in of answers that are clearly and undeniably generated by AI models and to this date they haven’t been marked helpful or denied by a moderator and thus those answers still exist. That’s just the moderator curation after the fact, let alone the nonsense, users have submitted themselves.

@SecurityHound I'm not talking about moderating. I'm talking about writing an answer: it's easy to use AI to write part of it and curate the AI output if needs be

@FranckDernoncourt - If it was easy the policy to ban GenAI wouldn’t be necessary. I have generated code from the most advanced models, had not already known what should be generated, I would have thought the code was high quality working code. Only reason I knew any different is because my decades of experience in the language

@SecurityHound I find it easy to curate in most cases, e.g. by simply running the code

@FranckDernoncourt - We will never agree code generated by these current models or even the upcoming models that have been announced generate helpful code. As long as the models are trained on code written by a human instead of just the specification of the language the models will continue to hallucinate

@SecurityHound they're trained on both

@FranckDernoncourt That is false, AI models do not understand language specifications, that is why they hallucinate.

@Dr.Snoopy I didn't say they understand l, which I know is a debatable term, but they are trained on it

@FranckDernoncourt So they can reproduce the language spec, you brought that up for a reason, but it means nothing for Stack Overflow.

@Dr.Snoopy they can do more than just reproducing the language spec

@FranckDernoncourt Too vague, they can only write code because they were trained on large quantities of code, but none of it means they understand the language specification.

@Dr.Snoopy My point is that the generated code can be useful to SO and that the language specification is also part of the training data.

@FranckDernoncourt You are not making the point you think you are making.

@FranckDernoncourt - Every single block of code generated I enhance ever asked ChatGPT and CoPilot to generate have had some issue, that is very difficult to stop and if it wasn’t for my literal 20 years  worth of experience in .NET I might have missed it. I have yet to use o3 but I don’t expect a huge leap in improvement as long as it’s being trained on code humans wrote. We are probably a decade away from AI being solely on the language standard and nothing else.

@SecurityHound a lot of the code I generated with 4o or o1-preview worked well for me. And I guess I'm not the only one: Google CEO says a quarter of the company’s new code is already AI generated

@FranckDernoncourt - Google also had employees in the past who believed their AI was self-aware.  I will never find AI-generated code helpful.

@SecurityHound There are outliers everywhere but the articles mentions 25% of the company’s new code is already AI generated, so it's not an isolated act.
Also: "According to Stack Overflow’s 2024 Developer Survey, over 75 percent of respondents are already using or are “planning to use” AI tools to assist with software development. Another survey by GitHub indicated that 92 percent of US-based developers are currently using AI coding tools."

No, for different reasons
Except in certain specific scenarios that are not widely applicable, training LLMs on the output of other LLMs has been shown to severely decrease output quality.
Stack Overflow's main revenue source is selling human-generated questions and answers to LLM vendors for training. If any significant fraction of this data was generated by LLMs, it wouldn't be useful for training and Stack Overflow couldn't continue to operate as a business.

Sounds like one more reason to allow LLM-generated content on SO, since most SE users disapprove SE Inc selling user content.

the suggestion of "shitting up the data set" out of spite, as a supporting argument for lifting the AIGC ban, just floors me. turned around, SE inc should do their damnedest to support efforts to keep "AIGC excrement" out of the data they sell.

Yes. Example: code generation.
GenAI has become really good at code generation. Nowadays, the best AI system is ranked #175 best human competitive coder on Codeforces (OpenAI official source; mirror of the Codeforces rating page on 2024-12-20), i.e. smokes almost all of us for code generation.
About Ryan M's valid concern:

The main problem with usage of generative AI tools on Stack Overflow is that people are wholesale copying content from them and often not checking its correctness at all [...] Vetting these answers at Stack Overflow's scale is infeasible,

Only allow users with a fair amount of rep, e.g. 10k, to use genAI, as they're much less likely to blindly copy-paste genAI output. Suspend users who posts incorrect content too often. Bad users shouldn't spoil the productivity of good users.
About Ryan M's other valid concern:

Stack Overflow questions cover a vast range of topics, including new libraries (or versions) that the public has no current experience with. Questions that follow the site's content guidelines (and are not duplicates) tend to not have straightforward answers that are already documented. Many require debugging, code inspection of dependencies, and trial and error—none of which are within the capabilities of current-generation generative AI systems.

Up to the user to write the proper prompt (e.g., possibly adding some docs in the prompt) and to decide if genAI is suited for a question. That's a skill for many present-day coders.
Therefore, I think it is about time that we start allowing the use of genAI on SO for code generation

"e.g. 10k, to use genAI, as they're much less likely to blindly copy-paste genAI output" Bullshit

@Makyen it's only 1 user, and maybe he didn't blindly copy paste.

@Makyen Are high-rep users more or less likely to post answers/questions containing AI-generated content?

The edit histories of a substantial number of that user's answers clearly indicate direct copy & pasting from AI on many occasions, often only going back and reviewing the content after the post had been downvoted or comments posted stating that it doesn't work. Given that a significant number of those answers could be searched for through the stock UI for at least a couple months after that question was posted (should no longer be possible), that's something that anyone could have determined.

This answer completely ignores the differences between competitive coding and writing code for Stack Overflow answers. Codeforces, based on a glance through a few example problems, appears to consist primarily of solving algorithm problems under highly constrained circumstances that have little to do with real-world coding (the rules appear to require humans to solve 5 problems in 2 hours, an unrealistic scenario).  This scenario is highly unrepresentative of the sorts of questions asked on Stack Overflow (which are, mostly, not algorithm problems).

All of your assumptions are either flawed or outright wrong (as explained by others). The mere suggestion of letting users posting (however many reps they have) answers bassed on work of others is concerning. First of all, that's akin to plagiarism. Second, what stops me from asking an LLM myself; if I am here, I am looking for answers from SMEs, not for someone to copy-paste my question into a text box and paste back the AIGC answer. Anyway, we don't need that on SO or anywhere else (I don't visit communities with relaxed policies on AIGC because I cannot trust the answers).

@M-- 1) just attribute the LLM. 2) I'm looking for good answers, regardless of how it was written

@RyanM this is a good point, that'd be interesting to rerun studies like https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392104/178179 on o3 or superior models

@Makyen how do you search for that?

@FranckDernoncourt Please read what I wrote, specifically: "(should no longer be possible)". There was discussion about how it was possible for anyone with the ability to see deleted posts to search for, or get from SEDE, at least a statistically significant portion of those answers at the time, due to a bug in the process of how they were deleted, specifically that, unlike normal, those deletions did not unaccept the answer. That was resolved by my going through and manually re-deleting all of the affected answers which were deleted at that time, causing them to be unaccepted.

Verifying those answers were no longer searchable that way was both part of verifying that method of resolving the problem that they were searchable would work (i.e., verifying that re-deleting them would make the answers non-searchable in that manner), and verifying that spending the not insubstantial time to re-delete the affected answers did, in fact, resolve the issue for those answers. So, as I said "(should no longer be possible)", at least in that way. Moderators, of course, can still search for them, but what I described above was something anyone could have determined at that time.

Attribute the LLM??? It's not like LLMs are writing those answers, they're spitting out something based off of work of others themselves. And, if one needs an answer, and don't care who writes it, they can just go ask the chatbot; we don't need mediators to talk to LLMs.

@M--  models only regurgitate infrequently https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/38431/4 and a chatbot is missing human curation

Bottom line for me is that it's not original work. In any case, what you propose could be a proposal for Area51, but not something for SO and the community does not seem so eager to adopt (ref answer score).
