What is the distribution of the number of AI-generated posts over the posters' reputation scores?
I was proposing:

Only allow users with a fair amount of rep, e.g. 10k, to use genAI, as they're much less likely to blindly copy-paste genAI output.

I was told it's BS, with a link to a example of a high-rep user who posted answers/questions containing AI-generated content.
What is the distribution of the number of AI-generated posts over the posters' reputation scores?
I assume mods can look at the rep of users who got suspended for posting answers/questions containing AI-generated and answer this question. I'm asking about past data.

The data is not available in any way that is remotely convenient, and SE has declined our prior proposals to make the data more conveniently available. What you've asked for would take a couple of weeks worth of full-time work, and what would be necessary would either be extremely laborious or excluded from being permitted, due to the contents of the Moderator Agreement, which substantially limits the processing we are permitted to do.

@Makyen Thanks, sorry to hear, I was unaware of that.

As written, this is primarily opinion based, as it asks for future projections, rather than just data about the past. It could be edited to be just about the past. However, as I mentioned above, it's unlikely to be answered. In addition, there isn't a clear correlation between what's being asked for here, assuming an edit to be just about the past, and the statement which the data is being proposed as posibly supporting.

Generally speaking, I don't think questions about statistics on how different groups of users act, are very useful on Meta. Discussion of why certain groups might act differently, might be. But questions like this one about AI use come across naturally as if they're setting up to push some sort of agenda.

@Makyen "I assume mods can look at the rep of users who got suspended for posting answers/questions containing AI-generated and answer this question." means it's about past data. But I've evited to make it clearer.

@KarlKnechtel was a way to assess if my proposal is supported by data.

@SecurityHound I believe this question is asking for the distribution of identified (and, thus, deleted) AI-generated posts.  (also, I believe your second sentence used the wrong verb.)

As currently asked, the answer is unknowable, because the reason a specific post was deleted is not recorded.  For example (this is not the only problem), one cannot assume that every post a moderator deletes when messaging or suspending someone for AI-generated content was AI-generated. Moderators delete posts for many reasons, and it is not uncommon, when looking through a user's posts to see which ones violate a rule that is being enforced against them, to find posts that need to be deleted for some other reason.

I think it's an interesting question aside from the premise, which I'm not a huge fan of if it's about writing posts which are primarily AIGC. if you use an LLM in the process of finding an answer and verify the answer, just write the answer in your own words.

Even if the data were [easily] obtainable, there's a huge bias in that data. Virtually all of the AI-generated content that mods remove is identified by users noticing that it is low-quality and flagging it for removal. Answers posted by high-reputation users are less likely to be scrutinized (both because of human observer bias, and also because of the intrinsic bias of certain site tools, like the review queues, which readily surface posts by new users), and thus less likely to be detected. Therefore, this question cannot be answered objectively, and is not a useful discussion anyway

@CodyGray objective!=biased therefore the question should not be closed

The question is closed because it's unanswerable, unproductive, and irrelevant. All of these make it an inappropriate question for Meta.

@CodyGray it is answerable, albeit not easily it seems. It is productive: biases a part of life. And it's relevant as it helps decide some SO policy.

What kind of policy it could help with? Allowing high reputation users to post AI crap, just because they have high reputation?

@FranckDernoncourt - AI generated content isn’t allowed to be submitted by anyone. That’s the policy.

@DalijaPrasnikar I've already posted the link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/432503/395857

@SecurityHound so what?

@FranckDernoncourt - So we already have a policy, GenAI is not allowed on this platform, and will never been seen as helpful

@SecurityHound The policy was being rediscussed on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/432500/395857

The newest models still hallucinate so I don’t see that policy changing

@SecurityHound If a model hallucinates 99% less than a human, you still don't see that policy changing?

@FranckDernoncourt - I absolutely don’t, I answer a lot of answers, in every case where someone uses GenAI to research they end up describing going down a rabbit hole of complete stupidity due to responses from even the most advanced reasoning models. So if these reasoning models are so good then I should be seeing less questions that are answered with 5 minutes of research by a human and that isn’t happening and I don’t see that happening with next years o3 model since OpenAI focused on decreasing the token costs not the quality of their response

@SecurityHound "due to responses from even the most advanced reasoning models." why do AI responses cause some humans to go down a rabbit hole  of complete stupidity?

@FranckDernoncourt - What? I have asked ChatGPT o1 a question and the answer I got was complete nonsense, had  not already known the expected answer, I might have thought the response was legitimate. I have seen questions describing research on a subject and the rabbit hole the user went down unfortunately wasn’t legitimate, the response they got from ChatGPT, was the nonsense. I am criticizing reasoning models and their response not the users who don’t have the knowledge to determine when they receive a nonsensical response from ChatGPT

@FranckDernoncourt How is AI generated code different from other AI generated crap? BTW, I have personally inspected hundreds of AI generated posts from high rep users and I can firmly say AI code is no better than the rest of it. Random nonsense is just random nonsense. And high rep users are producing equally bad AI answers like low rep users.

@DalijaPrasnikar "And high rep users are producing equally bad AI answers like low rep users." That's good to know, that'd be a good answer if the question wasn't closed. We're talking about code here as

@SecurityHound "I have asked ChatGPT o1 a question and the answer I got was complete nonsense, had not already known the expected answer" That contradicts my original question "If a model hallucinates 99% less than a human, you still don't see that policy changing?"

@FranckDernoncourt - A human might not understand the question but I rarely see a human answer a question that wasn’t even asked. I have seen a question mention apples, but the question was about growing oranges, and the response provided by these reasoning models talks about how to grow apple trees.

@SecurityHound we are assuming a model that hallucinates 99% less than a human so that should almost never happen

@FranckDernoncourt and why are we discussing this hypothetical model? I find it very hard to believe that this random number you're quoting is in any way accurate. You put too much weight on numbers that aren't as accurate / substantial as you think they are. You previously brought this up for Google where they said 25% of their new code was AI generated, how much of this involved rework/ re-prompting from the developer?  Please don't bring marketing numbers of these models and ask for policy changes.

@AbdulAzizBarkat "why are we discussing this hypothetical model" to make the case that strong models can be useful

That case can be made when such a model actually exists. If you want to make a case currently make it with actual facts rather than hypotheticals. Also this doesn't seem to be the point of this current question of yours so we're going off-topic here.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I made that point due to
Security Hound's comment "The newest models still hallucinate so I don’t see that policy changing"
